# Send a 'Stream' over a PutAsync request

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying my hand at .NET Core but I'm stuck trying to convert multipart/form-data to an application/octet-stream to send via a PUT request. Anybody have any expertise I could borrow?

```
[HttpPost("fooBar"), ActionName("FooBar")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFooBar() {
    HttpResponseMessage putResponse = await _httpClient.PutAsync(url, HttpContext.Request.Body);
}
```

**Update:** I think I might have two issues here:

1. My input format is multipart/form-data so I need to split out the file from the form data.
2. My output format must be application-octet stream but PutAsync expects `HttpContent`.

Comment: @user2864740 I tried:

```using (var stream = HttpContext.Request.Body) {
    HttpResponseMessage putResponse = await _httpClient.PutAsync(url, new StreamContent(stream));
}```

But maybe it's not being sent with the right Content-Type?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong when you use StreamContent? At first glance it seems like it should work. When debugging can you read the data in the request body? There's some config option that sets how big the content received from a HTTP request can be in ASP.NET, if your request surpasses that limit you won't be able to read it's contents (the default limit is 4mb I think).

Comment: Seems like the stream is just piping through the multipart/form-data instead of translating it to application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Request has a Form property that contains a Files property that has an `OpenReadStream()` function on it to convert it into a stream. How exactly I was supposed to know that, I'm not sure.

Either way, here's the solution:

```
StreamContent stream = new StreamContent(HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0].OpenReadStream());

HttpResponseMessage putResponse = await _httpClient.PutAsync(url, stream);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had been trying to do something similar and having issues. I needed to PUT large files (>1.5GB) to a bucket on Amazon S3 using a pre-signed URL. The implementation on [Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html) for .NET would fail for large files.

Here was my solution:

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);


    static async Task<bool> UploadLargeObjectAsync(string presignedUrl, string file)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Uploading " + file + " to bucket...");          

        try
        {
            StreamContent strm = new StreamContent(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            strm.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            HttpResponseMessage putRespMsg = await client.PutAsync(presignedUrl, strm);              
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```